# How EC2 allow SSH tunelling to access RDS in private subnet?

Tags: amazon-ec2, ssh, subnet, ssh-tunnel, private-subnet

To access RDS in private subnet, in the below architecture,

### [image]

Giving public IP of EC2, ssh private key location of EC2 in public subnet, DB credentials of RDS in private subnet, as shown below,

### [image]

How EC2(in public subnet) allow ssh tunneling to RDS in private subnet? Is it something to do with `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` in EC2?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. You should use another site on the [Stack Exchange network](https://stackexchange.com/sites) for this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the picture, the `EC2` instances share the same [private network (class B)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network) `172.16.X.X` with the `RDS` therefore by having access to any instance in the public segment and depending on the [security groups](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Overview.RDSSecurityGroups.html) defined on the `RDS` it may be possible to reach the database by doing something like:

```
ssh -L 3307:<db>.rds.amazonaws.com:3306 user@your.ec2
```

The option `-L` will do a local port forwarding from port `3307` (your computer) to port `3306` in `<db>.rds.amazonaws.com` going through `your.ec2.instance`.

You could use a `bastion` host to do this, you could read more about it here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quickstart/latest/linux-bastion/architecture.html

Besides defining how and what users to allow using ssh you will not have to deal with `sshd_config` most of the work will be either in AWS security groups or how you defined your [VPC](https://aws.amazon.com/vpc/) or network [ACL's.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-network-acls.html)

Comment: How *local port forwarding* concept relates to *ssh tunneling* concept in your answer?let me read this ... https://blog.trackets.com/2014/05/17/ssh-tunnel-local-and-remote-port-forwarding-explained-with-examples.html

Comment: Please close off-topic questions.