# Access Amazon RDS database in VPC from Lambda locally

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds, amazon-vpc

Is there any way we can access an Amazon RDS database inside VPC from Lambda locally (now in AWS console)?

I am trying to run lambda locally but having an issue while accessing RDS because of VPC.

Comment: Is the database in a Private subnet or a Public subnet? Is the database configured as "Publicly Available"?

Comment: If you need access locally resources from VPC, then you can use a client VPN with the VPC. However, maybe a public access with whitelisted IP on the security group is simpler to set up

Comment: Database is in private subnet and not configured as "Publicly Available" @JohnRotenstein

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your database is not accessible from the Internet. This is excellent for security, but it means you cannot connect directly to the database.

You have a couple of options...

You could create a **VPN Connection** into the VPC and then connect to the database.

Or, you could SSH into a 'Jump Box' (or 'Bastion Server') while using **Port Forwarding**. See: [StackOverflow: How EC2 allow SSH tunelling to access RDS in private subnet?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53821016/174777)